# Can you have foward slashes ('/') in ajax routes that match sub patterns (pyramid)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, routes, pyramid

I was playing around with ajax routes and it seems that the ajax route match only applies to the first forward slash '/'. Every thing beyond the first forward slash gets ignored.

For example.

**View.py**

```
@view_config(name="a", renderer="json")
def server_viewtest_a(request):
    return {}

@view_config(name="a/b", renderer="json")
def server_viewtest_ab(request):
    return {}
```

**test.js**

```
$.get('a/b', function (result) {  
 });
```

The above ajax call to route 'a/b' gets matched with 'server_viewtest_a' and not 'server_view_ab'. Every thing beyond the first forward slash gets ignored.

Is it possible to have forward slashes in ajax call routes? if so, how?

**Edit**

**For clarification, I can get it to work if I use the following code.  However, I wanted to use 'name' instead of 'route_name' in my @view_config so I don't have to define every route with "config.add_route()" in my __init__.py.  Is there a way to do it with just "name"?**

**__init__.py**

```
config.add_route('a', 'a')
config.add_route('a/b', 'a/b')
```

**View.py**

```
@view_config(route_name="a", renderer="json")
def server_viewtest_a(request):
    return {}

@view_config(route_name="a/b", renderer="json")
def server_viewtest_ab(request):
    return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route that matches the pattern `a/b`. I don't see one in your Python code.

Also I think that what you are experiencing is a result of [route declaration ordering](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#route-declaration-ordering), in which the second function is never evaluated. Usually your routes should be declared in order of most specific to least.

Assuming you use URL dispatch for route matching, instead of traversal, see [Adding View Configuration Using the @view_config Decorator](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#mapping-views-using-a-decorator-section) and [pyramid.view.view_config API documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/view.html#pyramid.view.view_config) for usage examples.

Comment: The routes are defined in the pythin code.  Since these are Ajax calls I use 'route'.